# Late entry in Survival Analysis

Tags: survival-analysis

I would like to ask how to deal with new entries of individuals in Survival Analysis.
I have a study about the time to event of several individuals who suffer from a disease. The study starts on a specified date (let's assume 1/1/2019). The individuals on this date are 50. The study lasts 6 months. In these 6 months, more individuals must be included but they were not present on the starting date.
I have not any left censoring because, for the new individuals, the time they enter the study, is the time the symptoms appeared. 
How should I deal with this late entry in the study?
I repeat the fact that, the date they enter, coincides with the manifestation of the disease.
We can imagine the individuals as patients if that makes things easier.

Comment: By new entries do you mean new type of categories in your data?

Comment: No. I mean new individuals. We can assume new patients that took part in the study later than the starting date.

Comment: And what is your purpose of this analysis? Is it a classification/regression problem?

Comment: Survival Analysis problem. Kaplan Meier estimation

Comment: Calculate times from entry into the study. (It's actually the people who already had the disease at the initiation of the study who are "left-censored".) The "survival" package functions are set up to handle interval data.